# Data Extension List Count Mismatch in UI and Api

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions

I am trying to retrieve the list of all the Data Extensions created for a Business Unit and i am successful in it. But, the problem is there is a mismatch in the count from the API and UI. In UI I see less number of Data Extensions compared to what I retrieved from the API.

May i know why this difference and can you guide me on how to filter only the data extensions that i see in UI?

SOAP envelope:

```xml
<soapenv:Body>
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <RetrieveRequest>
      <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
      <Properties>Name</Properties>
      <Properties>Description</Properties>
      <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
    </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: there are DE that are hidden in the UI, Like GA360 DE, Mobile filtered Lists, and some other system tables

Comment: Can you share what API you are using as well? REST/SOAP? What Endpoint/Object? This will help provide further context to your issue and help us give guidance.

Comment: @Gortonington Below is the SOAP request:

<soapenv:Body>
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <RetrieveRequest>
      <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
      <Properties>Name</Properties>
      <Properties>Description</Properties>
      <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
    </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</soapenv:Body>

Comment: @EazyE What i wanted to know id how to filter the hidden DE that we receive from the API.